# Почему в слове "русский" удвоенная с?

Tags: орфография, удвоенные-буквы

Почему в слове *русский* удвоенная с?

Answer (score 5):

В русском языке суффикс -ск- означает принадлежность к чему-либо. Был славянский этнос под названием росы или русы. Позднее, все народы, которые жили с ними бок о бок и их общие с славянами потомки стали называться русскими, как имеющие к ним отношение.
На историческую достоверность не претендую.

Answer (score 2):

Одно  "с"  от  корня,  другое  от  суффикса.

Answer (score 1):

Две "с" встали рядом не намеренно. Удвоение - по факту, случайное. Лучше даже так и не называть. Примеры: парнас-ский; форос-ский; спас-ский.